How to timestamp Jars being downloaded from virtual repo in artifactory?
I have set up a virtual repo to handle automatic Jar signing in Artifactory.
The Jars are signed correctly when downloaded from the virtual repo, except they aren't timestamped.
Is there a way to get the files timestamped using this approach?
I cannot find a setting in Artifactory to do so, so maybe I do not entirely understand the problem, or I just haven't found the right way to do this.
I'm using jarsigner -verify jarname.jar to perform the check.
The warning I'm seeing is: This jar contains signatures that do not include a timestamp.
